# In the SyFy show Defiance, Nolan figures out the Omec's cannot get back to their ship, so how does T'evgin get Kindzi to their ship?

Tags: defiance

In Defiance Season 3, Episode 06 - "Where the Apples Fell" Nolen figures out that T'evgin cannot get back to his ship.

> Nolen: This doesn't make any sense. Why wouldn't you help us? Unless
>   you can't. Ohh... That trip down from orbit, **that was assisted by
>   gravity**, wasn't it? That's pretty easy, but the **trip back up into
>   orbit, that takes a lot more energy**. That's the hard part. **You two are
>   stranded here. You're stuck, you're weak**, and you're lying so we don't
>   find out about it, am I right?

Season 3, Episode 9, "Ostinato in White"  Kindzi is responsible for the deaths and after a confrontation with her father T'evgin, she is put into stasis onboard the Omec ship.

> T'evgin: Yes... you will!
>
> [dramatic music] [device whirring] ♪ ♪
>
> Kindzi: [whimpering]
>
> T'evgin: And I am tired of teaching you. Good-bye, Kindzi. [funky bass music]

He had the drones hover over her, and at that point in the episode we weren't sure what happened to Kindzi.

Season 3, Episode 10 "When Twilight Dims the Sky Above"

> T'evgin: Enough! You are forbidden to feed.
>
> Kindzi: Why? Indogene were created for that very purpose.
>
> T'evgin: Good-bye, Kindzi. **You will sleep with your family until you learn
>   your place.** I made a mistake.

So we learn at the beginning recap on the next show that Kindzi was transported to the Omec ship orbiting in the sky.

9/15/15 Edit:
I wanted to add that there's an additional problem with flying or sending something into orbit.

> **Electromagnetic distortion** created by the malfunctioning Votanformers
>   **have rendered most long-distance communication and air transit impossible**, isolating far-flung regions much as they would have been
>   isolated in the 19th century. Low-flying aircraft such as helicopters
>   are still safe to fly, and will still function, **but high-altitude
>   long-distance flights are too dangerous**; neither the humans nor the
>   Votans **are capable of launching vehicles into Earth's orbit
>   anymore**, as it is not only dangerous, but prohibitively expensive
>   for societies that only just managed to pull themselves back from
>   complete collapse.
>   (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defiance_(TV_series))

Above just another tidbit to think about, but clearly it's established that the Omec do not have the power to reach orbit, at least four episodes ago.

If they were only able to travel down from the ship with the aid of gravity, and they didn't have enough power to travel back up to the ship, how was T'evgin able to get Kindzi back up to the ship?

Comment: Why would somebody downvote this answer? It's specific, well thought out, uses in canon/universe references, and is  thoroughly framed. I'd appreciate it if when people downvote they at least leave a comment letting the OP know why. I leave comments for people, they are often helpful.

Answer (score 2):

By getting enough energy. They are in the possession of a gulanite mine. That is where they get their energy from.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You did misspell gulanite so I corrected it. Do you have any further info so you can round your answer out a bit. This episode happened only four weeks after the episode where Nolan reveals they don't have the energy to fly back to the ship. In addition there's a problem with flying from the surface anyway, which I will add to my question, I should have had it in in the first place, sorry about that. Can you further expound as how 4 weeks of additional mining would make a difference in them being able to return to the ship? +1 for effort

Comment: Worth noting that the time between episodes is not necessarily constant. There's no reason to assume that 4 episodes = 4 weeks.

Comment: @Roger there's no reason to assume that it doesn't. If you remember between the first and second season there was a miniseries released on their website to show what happened between the two seasons. If you have a better theory as to how much time passed I'm interested to hear it. Either way whether it's 4 weeks, 6 weeks, 8 weeks, or 10 weeks it's still astonishing that there's no mention of where they're at with the gulanite and all of a sudden he has no problem sending her to the ship, and I'm assuming after this episode she returns the favor to him? Gonna watch it tonight, so don't know yet

Answer (score 0):

High-altitude flying is no longer a problem since the end of season 2 (which is why the VC has also resumed long-distance high-altitude flights). This is also mentioned in one of the episodic fun facts on the Syfy site iirc. As for the energy source, four weeks, at least, of gulanite mining with Omec technology could very well be enough to resume full functioning of the Tsuroz and its pods/drones/etc.